# Selenium webdrivers used on different computers/paths

Tags: java, git, testing, selenium, webdriver

I'm doing a project with a couple others where we use Selenium for automated tests. We use a Git in order to share our code, but everytime we check it in we need to update the path to the drivers since they exist locally on each computer.

It looks something like this:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:/Path/chromedriver.exe");
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

We have tried searching for a long time now and cannot come up with a solution to our problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to tell git to assume that the file is unchanged.

This is also known as temporarily ignoring files.

You don't want to put them in .gitignore because you still need the file, you just need to tell git to not pay attention to it for the time being, so git will ignore it if it changes for you locally.

There's a good guide [here](http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/18/temporarily-ignoring-files.html) on how to do this from the command line, or if you are using something like **TortoiseGit** you could do this in the following way:

1. Check for modifications in the folder your locally changed file resides in. You can do this by right-clicking in the folder -> TortoiseGit -> Check for modifications.

[image]

2. Choose the file you want to temporarily ignore and "Assume Unchanged" will appear among the options.

[image]

Note that this needs to be done on every local machine since everyone will want to ignore the changes they've made to the file.

Also note that if you need to check in changes to the same file as the path often, I'd suggest injecting the path from a separate file which would not need to be checked in that often.

A simple example with a separate constant class could look like this:

*SeleniumSettings.java*

```
public class SeleniumSettings {
    public static final String CHROME_DRIVER_PATH = "C:/Path/chromedriver.exe";
}
```

Then in your original class you could call your property setter in the following way:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",SeleniumSettings.CHROME_DRIVER_PATH);
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

**Alternatively:** you could create a template file containing the default configuration and then everyone would copy the template and adjust the path to their own, and the adjusted file based on the template can be added to the .gitignore file, since the template will still be fetched for everyone.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! I have also thought about having a settings file separately which you do not change. Issue there is that I don't know how such a file would look or how to implement it.

Comment: Added a simple example if you ever will need to do this kind of thing again. :)

Comment: Thanks alot! Would upvote you too if I only had the points for it, haha! I will actually implement this anyway since I believe it will help us further.

Answer (score 1):

Put it inside a folder in your project and provide only the relative path.
So it would be somewhat like:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","webdrivers/chromedriver.exe");
```

So here you can see `webdrivers` is a folder under your current project. So everyone can give this relative path and once you have checked in chromedriver to git in the given folder it won't ask for chromedriver too. But do remember to maintain chromedriver version unique throughout your team.

Comment: While this solves the problem, the other answer might be better. It happens often that the members of a team need their own configuration files, so it's better to use git built-in ignore.